# How to find dbcreatestruct method in mule esb3.8.4 jar file?

Tags: mule, mule-el

Recently i want to use UDT while inserting data into db through procedure call.Now UDT is supported in Mule ESB 3.8.4 version.They have given some example in MULE-11138 jira task.But when i am using MEL function defined in above task.I am getting 
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.enhydra.jdbc.standard.StandardXAConnectionHandle.createStruct(Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/sql/Struct;

Can any one help me on this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i am able to resolve this error all i need to do is to use type defined in db directly for creation of array or struct like.

dbCreateArray('Oracle_Configuration', 'APPS.CONTACT_INFO_ASYNC_TAB_TYPE', payload);

Thanks,
Anurag

Answer (score -1):

@Anurag

This is available only in enterprise edition.

Comment: I am using EE version